# android-recycleview inside scrollview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-scrollview

In my activity , I want to put a slideShow above my page and then put recycleview after that, to do so ,I'v written this code in my layout:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#fff"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="6dp">


    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        card_view:cardBackgroundColor="#fff"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="3dp"
        card_view:cardElevation="0dp">

        <cn.trinea.android.view.autoscrollviewpager.AutoScrollViewPager
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="250dp" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
</LinearLayout>
```

the problem with this code is that when I run the activity , only the recycleview scrolls , I don't want that, I want if I scroll down ,the whole page scrolls down not just the recycle .

How can I make the whole page scroll ?

Comment: Nested scrollable views are discouraged in android. Why don't you include your `AutoScrollViewPager` as part of your `RecyclerView` item ?

Answer (score 3):

Three steps to do this:

1. Replace your scrollview with NestedScrollView with layout behaviour set to `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"`
2. Keep all your widgets under a linear/relative layout(because nested scroll view accepts only one child)
   3.create CustomLinearLayoutManager.java with this code:

   ```
   public class CustomLinearLayoutManager extends LinearLayoutManager {

   public CustomLinearLayoutManager(Context context, int orientation, boolean reverseLayout)    {
       super(context, orientation, reverseLayout);
   }

   private int[] mMeasuredDimension = new int[2];

   @Override
   public void onMeasure(RecyclerView.Recycler recycler, RecyclerView.State state,
                         int widthSpec, int heightSpec) {
       final int widthMode = View.MeasureSpec.getMode(widthSpec);
       final int heightMode = View.MeasureSpec.getMode(heightSpec);
       final int widthSize = View.MeasureSpec.getSize(widthSpec);
       final int heightSize = View.MeasureSpec.getSize(heightSpec);
       int width = 0;
       int height = 0;
       for (int i = 0; i < getItemCount(); i++) {
           measureScrapChild(recycler, i,
                   View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(i, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
                   View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(i, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
                   mMeasuredDimension);

           if (getOrientation() == HORIZONTAL) {
               width = width + mMeasuredDimension[0];
               if (i == 0) {
                   height = mMeasuredDimension[1];
               }
           } else {
               height = height + mMeasuredDimension[1];
               if (i == 0) {
                   width = mMeasuredDimension[0];
               }
           }
       }
       switch (widthMode) {
           case View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY:
               width = widthSize;
           case View.MeasureSpec.AT_MOST:
           case View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED:
       }

       switch (heightMode) {
           case View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY:
               height = heightSize;
           case View.MeasureSpec.AT_MOST:
           case View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED:
       }

       setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
   }

   private void measureScrapChild(RecyclerView.Recycler recycler, int position, int widthSpec,
                                  int heightSpec, int[] measuredDimension) {
       View view = recycler.getViewForPosition(position);
       if (view != null) {
           RecyclerView.LayoutParams p = (RecyclerView.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
           int childWidthSpec = ViewGroup.getChildMeasureSpec(widthSpec,
                   getPaddingLeft() + getPaddingRight(), p.width);
           int childHeightSpec = ViewGroup.getChildMeasureSpec(heightSpec,
                   getPaddingTop() + getPaddingBottom(), p.height);
           view.measure(childWidthSpec, childHeightSpec);
           measuredDimension[0] = view.getMeasuredWidth() + p.leftMargin + p.rightMargin;
           measuredDimension[1] = view.getMeasuredHeight() + p.bottomMargin + p.topMargin;
           recycler.recycleView(view);
       }
   }
   ```

   }

set adapter to your recyclerview like this:

```
CustomLinearLayoutManager customLinearLayoutManager = new CustomLinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
        updatesRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        updatesRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(customLinearLayoutManager);
        updatesRecyclerView.setAdapter(yourAdapter);
        updatesRecyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
```

That's it , it works.

Comment: thanks very much for reply , just one more thing , I'm using GridLayoutManager for my recycleview , how can I use gridlayout ?

Comment: GridLayoutManager extends LinearLayoutManager ,i have not really tried it with gridlayoutmanager . ideally minor tweaks to above code should work for gridlayoutmanager too...